# Flutter web cannot visit url

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-routes

In flutter web, how can I open certain page via full address?

The scenario is:

1. Open a classroom page route like
   `await Navigator.pushNamed(context, "classroom/detail/$id", arguments: {"data": someData});`
2. Classroom page is opened and the address bar will contains URL like `http://localhost/myschoolweb/classroom/detail/1`
3. I press `F5` to refresh the page -> **ERROR 404**
4. Open new tab and visit aforementioned address -> **ERROR 404**

This is my `onGenerateRoute` code:

```
onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
  List<String> routes = settings.name?.split("/") ?? [];
  final routeName = routes.isNotEmpty ? routes.first : null;
  final routeSub1 = routes.length > 1 ? routes[1] : null;
  final routeSub2 = routes.length > 2 ? routes[2] : null;

  final args = {
    ...(settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>? ?? {}),
    "sub1": routeSub1,
    "sub2": routeSub2,
  };

  Widget page = const SplashPage();
  switch (routeName) {
    case ROUTE_CLASS: page = ClassPage(args); break;
    // other routes ...
  }

  Future.microtask(() => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode()));
  return MaterialPageRoute(
    settings: settings,
    builder: (context) {
      // other scripts ...
      return page;
    }
  );
},
```

*I suspect it'll be translated to `classroom/detail/1/index.html` which is of course non-existent on the server?*

ps:
I use this library to simplify the web url: https://pub.dev/packages/url_strategy

Comment: Check out Flutter Navigator 2, [for example here](https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade), if set up properly, it can do what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just in case anybody need it, I have solved this on apache server using .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.html|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.png)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.html [L]
```

So any URL will now defaults to index.html.